# Instance checking in an arraylist of an interface

Tags: java

So I have this CopyOnWriteArrayList, where GameObject is an interface. Throughout the program I am adding to this arraylist a bunch of different types of GameObjects. I was wondering if it is possible to iterate through this arraylist and check if the GameObject is an instance of the object given (using a parameter in a method. Here is generally what I mean:

```
public <T extends Object> List<T> getObjectsOfType(Class<T> type) {
    ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
    for (Object obj : objects) {
        if (/*match?*/) {
            list.add((T) obj);
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

So where is says "match?", I want to check if the object is in any way related to the Class type. I  also want it to work if the GameObject implements "type".

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - you can use [`isAssignableFrom`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29) method of the `Class<T> type`:

```
if (type.isAssignableFrom(obj.getClass())) {
    list.add((T) obj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use generics to solve this problem.  It appears your method is accepting a list of objects, so I assume your placing your `GameObject`s into a list that looks something like this.

```
List<Object> gameObjects = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

If you switch your list to use a generic that only accepted `GameObject` there would be no need for type checking.

```
List<GameObject> gameObjects = new ArrayList<GameObject>();
```

Comment: I did this before, but the purpose of this entire thing is to be able to add any GameObject, without having to create more arraylists.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [isInstance()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance%28java.lang.Object%29) method from Class:

```
if (type.isInstance(obj)) {
    list.add(type.cast(obj));
}
```

I'd also suggest using type.[cast()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast%28java.lang.Object%29) method for casting `obj` instead of a `(T)` cast.  The latter will give you a compile-time warning, while using `type.cast()` will not.